# Is there any difference in meaning between "I count on you" and "I'm counting on you"?

Tags: difference, present-continuous, present-simple

Is there any difference in meaning between *I count on you* and *I'm counting on you*? For example:

> **I count on** you to come through with what you promised.
>
> **I'm counting on** you to come through with what you promised.

Comment: Do you not see any difference in tense? For example, "The kids drive her mad" and "The kids are driving her mad" Where is the minimal research or  the reason why you are asking?

Comment: Come on, now, Dmytro.  By now, you really should have absorbed; I speak French versus I'm speaking French. When to use simple present versus present continuous.

Comment: Sure I can see there is a difference in the use of tense. What I can't see is the difference in meaning between the two. I know in which situations the tenses are used. But in my example, I can't feel the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the usual difference between simple present and present continuous.

Simple present gives a fact that is generally true, and not implied to be temporary.  Present continuous is for temporary conditions.

"I count on you always"/ "I'm counting on you now, in the current situation".